# Why Sprite Kit can't find a resource after a bunch of time running?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have the same sound.mp3;

I am using 
SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"sound.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
[self runAction:sound];

It works fine at first, but after a bunch of time running, it says termination because can't find resource: sound.mp3.
So I change it to _sound in the implementation. Sometimes it still shows can't find resource.

Now another problem shows:`

```
SKSpriteNode *missile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ThinMissileR"];
         int minY = _bottomSpike.size.height + missile.size.height/2;
         int maxY = self.size.height - _topSpike.size.height - missile.size.height/2;
         int rangeY = maxY - minY;
         int emmitY = arc4random()% rangeY + minY;
         missile.position = CGPointMake(- missile.size.width/2, emmitY);
         missile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:missile.size];
         missile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = missileCategory;
         missile.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

         [self addChild:missile];

         SKEmitterNode *fire = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FireParticleR" ofType:@"sks"]];
         fire.position = CGPointMake(-missile.size.width + 5, 0);
         [missile addChild:fire];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Attemped to add nil node', reason: 'Attemped to add nil node to parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'ThinMissileR' (102 x 24)] position:{-25.5, 399} size:{51, 12} rotation:0.00'

It also terminates after a bunch of time playing. Says I am adding a nil node to parent.

Can someone explain why there is such problem in Sprite Kit?
Or tell me how to release the memory every time the SKScene changes? Thanks!

Comment: A node can only have one parent.

Comment: @sangony All those error only appear after several mins play, is it possible because out of memory?

Comment: The error message you posted means you are trying to add your fire node to a non-existing parent node. Your issue is not your fire node but rather the adding and removing of the missile node. Memory has nothing to do with this error message.

Comment: You think? Add an exception breakpoint, then you are more likely to *know* what happens. Perhaps you're simply running out of memory, check memory usage with Instruments.

Comment: @sangony this error message never shows up again, I found the memory is getting higher and higher and when the memory is more than 40MB, it will come out of a error message says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Failed to Load Resource', reason: 'Resource ClickButtonSound.mp3 can not be loaded'"

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The memory getting higher as the Scene changes, and when the memory is high, it comes up with failed to load resource